# Exporting DataGridView to SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, datagridview, export

I have a DataGridView that contains data which has been successfully imported from a .csv file using the code below. The columns in the DGV can be reordered by the user. I need to export the data to a SQL Server database using the columns' DisplayIndex order rather than the Index order.

```
    private void btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char colDelimiter = ',';
        char rowDelimiter = '\r';
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();


        OpenFileDialog getFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        getFile.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        getFile.FilterIndex = 1;

        if(getFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = getFile.FileName;
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(getFile.FileName);
            string[] columns = reader.ReadLine().Split(colDelimiter);

            int x = 0;
            foreach(string c in columns)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(columns[x]);
                x += 1;
            }
            x = 0;

            string[] rows = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(rowDelimiter);
            foreach (string r in rows)
            {
                string[] record = r.Split(colDelimiter);
                dataTable.Rows.Add(record);
            }

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            MessageBox.Show(fileName + " was successfully imported.");

        }
```

Comment: Does the table already exist or do you need to create that too?

Comment: @RyanB The table already exists. However, there is no guarantee that the column names in the csv will match that of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is the best solution I know of: Create a new table based on the dataGridView's displayed table. Then replace the original DataTable with the new one. I'm assuming you have some DataTable called table in this example.

Hope this helps and I wish there was a simpler way, but if you're doing a large Update() command this is the easiest approach I know.

If you're doing something where you manually update each line with a SQL query or something though you can just make sure the update goes based on the DisplayIndex and the DataGridView rather than the DataTable directly.

```
//Make a new DataTable
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
//Create Columns based on DataGridView headers
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    newTable.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
}
//Add each row of data from DataGridView into new DataTable in the displayed order
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRow();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        newRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
    }
    newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
//Set your original DataTable to the new DataTable with the correct ordering
table = newTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as a note, I was looking at how you originally load the .csv...

I have something similar where I'm splitting based on delimiters and I just make sure to include a Schema.ini where my .csv is being loaded from and then use ADO commands to populate the DataTable. This seems to work much faster for me.

See my Schema.ini which splits at commas:

```
[tempdata.csv]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
```

Here is the #include command:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Here is the C# code to populate my DataTable using the dataAdapter Fill(), set the binding source to the DataTable, and then set the DataSource for my dataGridView to the binding source:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + workingPath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(|)\"";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + workingFilename, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            originalTable = new DataTable("");
            dAdapter.Fill(originalTable);
        }
    }
```